# Invalid characters in XML Atom feed

Tags: bug, status-review, feed, xml

The issue popped again as I initially reported here: [issue #15320 Stack Overflow - Other](https://support.stackenterprise.co/support/tickets/15320)

Consequence was that Thunderbird was unable to load the feed, until the invalid characters slid out of the RSS.

The error that popped on this feed because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70510115/gdb-unable-to-jump-to-specified-address-location) is now gone but here is the error reported by the W3C validator:

> Sorry
> This feed does not validate.
>
> ```
> line 206, column 1357: XML parsing error: <unknown>:206:1357: reference to invalid character number [help]
>
>     ... /p&gt;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;&#xA0;&#x13; &#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pr ...
>                                                  ^
> ```

If you [run the W3C validator today](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffeeds%2Ftag%3Ftagnames%3Dbash%26sort%3Dnewest), it sill reports an issue with the namespace:

> This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.
>
> ```
> line 2, column 0: Use of unknown namespace: http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0 [help]
>
>     <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:re="http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0">
> ```

Post that caused the invalid characters in the RSS feed:

---

###### Related references

- Similar `status-completed` issue: [Invalid XML in Atom feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220871/479836)
- Problematic post: [GDB unable to jump to specified address location [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70510115/gdb-unable-to-jump-to-specified-address-location)
- Stack Enterprise issue tracker: [issue #15320 Stack Overflow - Other](https://support.stackenterprise.co/support/tickets/15320)

Comment: If the issue was reported to stack enterprise - is it also affecting paid products? I'm going to status-review this, since feeds are a useful thing but I suspect 'who' deals with it and how might differ

Comment: @JourneymanGeek based on [Did Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange shift from Jira Service Management to something new?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372717/241919), I think it's not only for paid products.